# QUnit asyncTest what's the difference?

Tags: javascript, jquery, qunit

Suppose I have the following code without asyncTest

```
setTimeout(function(){
  test ("test1", function(){
    ok(true, "test1 works");
  }); 
}, 2000);
```

And, this code with asynTest

```
asyncTest ("test1", function(){
  setTimeout(function(){
    ok(true, "test1 works");
    start();
  }, 2000);
});
```

My question is what are the difference between these 2? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Taken from the qUnit [**documentation**](http://docs.jquery.com/QUnit/asyncTest):

> Asynchronous tests added are queued and run one after the other.
>   Equivalent to calling a normal test() and immediately calling stop().

While [**setTimeout**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.setTimeout) :

> Calls a function or executes a code snippet after specified delay.

The difference is that seTimeout has nothing to do with qUnit and simple executes the specified code snippet after the specified amount of time, while qUnit's `asyncTest` does not execute after a specified amount of time but instead is placed on a queue from which it eventually gets picked up and executed.

Also I don't think you are really comparing like-with-like.

Comment: Now I get it. Thanks. I was dumb enough to not be able to tell apple and orange apart.